# VS.NET I need assistance with catch

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, google-chrome, try-catch, voip

I require help with the program I'm beginning to write in VB.NET.

The program needs to open a web page in Chrome. On the 20 PCs we have here, some of them have Chrome installed and some of them have new Chrome. I have no idea what the new Chrome is, but it appears to exist.

I want the program to scan the computer for an installation of Chrome. If Chrome isn't found then the program should now search for the new Chrome. If neither of them are found then display a dialogue box to alert the user that Chrome isn't installed properly.

My code so far is as follows:

```
Try

If voiptools.Checked = True Then Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe", "--new-window https://toolshd.dcn.ote.gr/voiptools/") 

Catch

If voiptools.Checked = True Then Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\new_chrome.exe", "--new-window https://toolshd.dcn.ote.gr/voiptools/")

End Try
```

So far so good, but I cannot figure out how to display a message box when it cannot find either Chrome or new Chrome.

I want to thank you for your patience, because I'm just starting out.

Many wishes for the new year.

Comment: Since Chrome is an evergreen browser, what do you mean by "new Chrome"? Have you disabled Chrome's automatic update?

Answer (score 2):

Do not drive a program trying to handle exceptions. In particular if there are tools that helps you avoid the most common case of exceptions. In your case I would use the File.Exists (Imports System.IO) to check if the file exists or not.

```
Dim chrome As String = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
Dim newchrome As String = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\new_chrome.exe"
Dim prms = "--new-window https://toolshd.dcn.ote.gr/voiptools/"
Try
If voiptools.Checked = True Then 
  If File.Exists(chrome) Then
     Process.Start(chrome, prms) 
  Else If File.Exists(newchrome) Then 
     Process.Start(newchrome, prms) 
  Else
     ' write here your message for your users ' something like alert("No suitable file to launch found")
  End If
Catch ex as Exception
     ' write here your handler for exceptional situations (log, message)
End Try

Sub alert(msg as string)
    string script = "alert(" & msg & ");";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), 
                  "ServerControlScript", script, true);
End Sub
```

Notice that you still have to use a Try Catch block because everytime you work with the file system you risk to incur in exceptional situations on which you have no controls (permissions, file deleted by user, etc...)